# Magento Magmi Alphabetize Categories and SubCategories

Tags: magento, categories, magmi

When I run the Magmi category import it adds new categories to the bottom of the order.  I need the category names and their subcategory names sorted alphabetically...always.. I am using a Category menu extender which does not have auto sort capabilities... So editing the phtml will not be easy...
I have was thinking to write sql to provide what the level and position SHOULD be but see no way in magmi to upload that data?

I have tried to manually move the categories and that works but since new cats come and go it would be to tedious.

This seems to be a common problem, I am surprised it has not found its way into becoming a feature..

I COULD clear all categories by running the removecats.sql in magmi but that seems like I am asking for trouble long term.

I do want to have whatever I upload to be the only categories and the only items in those categories on the site.. would you suggest that I do clear then load?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since Magmi 0.7.18, you can specify a numeric position for each category in the import CSV file. I'd recommend using Excel to sort your Categories alphabetically and then insert the position column and autofill the position down the rows. You can then save the file as a CSV and import.

Here's the [Magmi wiki page](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=On_the_fly_category_creator/importer#Defining_category_options) describing the position setting (bottom of page)

Comment: I saw that page.. it discusses item positioning within the category.. I am trying to order the category and sub categories themselves?  Is there any better docs showing the category_id being used in magmi?